# Does this queue-like data structure have a name?

Tags: data-structures

It's quite simple with only two operations, you can either push a value, or get all values, clearing all these values from the structure. Can be easily implemented with a queue aggregate.

- `push(value)`
- `get() -> list of values, clears contents`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, there is no common name for a data structure which provides this functionality. Depending on the list order provided by `get()` it is similar to a *stack* or a *queue*.

Assuming Java, this could work for you (not tested):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Stack;

public class FlushStack<E> extends Stack<E> {

    public Collection<E> get() {
        ArrayList<E> elements = new ArrayList<E>(this);
        this.clear();
        return elements;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah i think you are right, couldn't find any names for it so I followed your suggestion and called it Flush* :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is basically a stack, only that "get" does a recurring "pop" until the stack is empty.
In pseudocode this would be something like:

```
def push (v): stack.push (v)

def get ():
    retVal = []
    while stack.isNotEmpty: retval += [stack.pop () ]
    return retVal
```